# css :target selector one link targeting two div's?

Tags: css, html, class, hyperlink

I am trying to make a simple mobile menu toggle with only CSS. By showing and hiding two buttons with both different links to classes that either show or hide the navigation menu.

It is a edit of this tutorial [link](https://shellcreeper.com/full-css-responsive-navigation-toggle-no-javascript/), but now I want to have the close and open buttons to be in a saperate div (header div) and I have problems targetting the navigation to show or hide.

Somehow I can't get the links right to target the menu.

So the working part is that I have a div wich contains two links that show and hide eachother like a toggle button [link](http://www.drummersantana.nl/rieon15.html)

Now I want them to allso show and hide the menu. What I changed from the tutorial is that the toggle buttons aren't in the same div anymore and now I can't get them to target the navigation. So it is a HTML/CSS markup problem that I have.

This is what I've got so far, I guess it's a simple thing but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
<style>
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
}
/* Hide Menu*/
#mainmenu{
    display: none;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}

/* Display Menu Items */
#header:target #mainmenu{
    display: block;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;

}
/* Hide Open Toggle Link */
#header:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Show Close Toggle Link */
#header:target #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

The HTML code

```
<div class="header-div" id="header">
<div id="buttons-container" >
            <a href="#header" class="open-menu-primary"><span>menu</a>
            <a href="#" class="close-menu-primary"><span>close</span></a>
</div>
</div>
  <nav class="navigation" id="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">main1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">main2</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub2/a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">main3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SanMoll/k8ej4fmo/)

Smal update, the tutorial is making use of the :target selector here is the w3school discription: URLs with an # followed by an anchor name, link to a certain element within a document. The element being linked to is the target element. The :target selector can be used to style the current active target element. w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Comment: This i my understanding of your question: two buttons v and h. If the user click v the menu should be visible, if the user click h the menu should be hidden. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is it. And the buttons should themselves allso swap from being shown or hidden. See this working [link] (http://www.drummersantana.nl/rieon15.html) I only want to get the buttons in a saperate div, that is where the problem starts for me. Do I need to refrase my question?

Comment: Smal update, the tutorial is making use of the :target selector here is the w3school discription: URLs with an # followed by an anchor name, link to a certain element within a document. The element being linked to is the target element.

The :target selector can be used to style the current active target element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really could do with simplifying your code. For this instance you don't need the divs. and you only need one link to toggle the menu - why put one link in a div? See below

```css
label {  
  cursor: pointer;
}
   #menu {
 display: none; /* hide the checkbox */
   }
   .mainmenu {
 display: none;
   }
   #menu:checked + .mainmenu {
 display: block;
  }

   nav{display:none;}

   label{color:blue;text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<label for="menu">Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menu">
<ul class="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
  <li><a href="">main1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="hover-sub"><a href="javascript:void(0)">main2</a>
    <ul id="submenu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="" class="con">main3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw37d491/2/)

Comment: Hi Rachel, that is nice :-) Thank you! But it should be possible without JQuery it is a simple targeting/markup problem I guess. I had a Javascript version working like this too but then I had problems with Android so this pure CSS version would be my first choise. Can you tell where I make a targeting mistake?

Comment: @Santana the css was far more complex than it needed to be really, took me a while to figure it out. Once i simplified it, it was much easier to work with.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I will do some cleaning then :-)

Comment: actually this is much simpler http://www.outofscope.com/css-only-menu-toggle-no-javascript-required/ here is a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/aw37d491/

Comment: yeah but I have a targeting problem, did you check the tutorial I am trying to adjust? Cause that is the one, it is simple and pure CSS, your links have both javascripting. It really could work like that but I don't understand how it works when you target a class trhough a link. See this exsample and how far I got. [link](https://shellcreeper.com/full-css-responsive-navigation-toggle-no-javascript/) and [link](http://www.drummersantana.nl/rieon15.html)

Comment: the second one doesn't did you check the link after the codepen

Comment: @Santana i reedited baout 20 mins after i last posted - i realised i'd made a mistake. Please review my answer again.

Comment: I very much apreciate your effort but I am trying to learn something here and I am not looking for a workaround. I could use a bootstrap approach or one of you exsamples, but I am making my own template that is why I need to separate the menu from the button. It has to do with the desigh I made. The question is; targeting classes through a link/anchor. So that is what I am trying to figure out. I hope you can give some inside on that and I will be happy to give you a upvote or a accept :-)

Comment: it would help if you would post your fulll html as i don;t see why this wouldn't work. at least upvote me. i spent quite a bit of time on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84919/discussion-between-santana-and-rachel-gallen).

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in making a [dropdown menu](http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/Cdwzq)

(This one creates just a regular css dropdown menu and uses regular transitions in the CSS:)

```
* {transition:all 0.3s;-webkit-transition:all 0.3s;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
.header-nav {position:relative;float:left;margin:0 auto;}
.header-nav ul {position:absolute;float:left;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.header-nav ul li {position:relative;float:left;border-left:4px solid rgba(224, 52, 106, 1);}
.header-nav ul li ul {margin-left:-4px;}
.header-nav > ul {position:relative;}
.header-nav > ul > li:last-child {border-right:4px solid rgba(224, 52, 106, 1);}
```

or a [toggle button](http://codepen.io/mrnathan8/pen/mgFqJ) for a menu?

(This one uses transitions and HTML checkboxes to create the toggle button:)

```
.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .horizontal {opacity: 0;}
.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-1 {transform:rotate(405deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(405deg);margin-top:10px;}
.spinner-master input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .spinner-spin > .diagonal.part-2 {transform:rotate(-405deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-405deg);margin-top:-16px;}
```

Comment: Hi Clare and thanks for your time. I am trying to make a toggling button ( two buttons hiding eachother) One with a action that show the menu and one that hide it again.

Comment: Here is a working version of it but I want the menu close and open buttons in the header div, that's where the targetting gets messed up. [link](http://www.drummersantana.nl/rieon15.html) I will try to make a clean Fiddle out of it for the eas of reading.

Answer (score 0):

As allways the answer is more simple then you think of in the first place. So I target the element that contains both the targets I want to target. See the code and the Fiddle.

CSS code:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
}
#buttons-container {
    background-color: #006cad;
    text-align:right;
    padding:16px;
}
/* Hide Menu*/
#mainmenu{
    display: none;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Display Menu Items */
#wrap:target .navigation #mainmenu{
    display: block;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;

}
/* Hide Open Toggle Link */
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Show Close Toggle Link */
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="header" id="header">
<div id="buttons-container" >
                <a href="#wrap" class="open-menu-primary"><span>menu</a>
                <a href="#" class="close-menu-primary"><span>close</span></a>
</div>
</div>
      <nav class="navigation" id="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="">main1</a></li>
        <li id="hover-sub"><a href="javascript:void(0)">main2</a>
          <ul id="submenu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="con">main3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SanMoll/k8ej4fmo/10/)